# Can't get my texture to show up in 3D view

Tags: rendering, 3d-view

I can make blender 2.79 sit up and beg but I'm coming up to speed on 2.91 and the learning curve is... significant. Today's problem:

I have a model with a UV diffuse texture and I can't get the texture to show up in 3D view. It's just black.

- 3D view is showing materials, render pass "Diffuse Color". This is working for other meshes in scene.
- Mesh has a "Principled BDSF" shader with "CGX" and "Christiansen/Burley"
- Shader has my texture as the base color
- Texture file shows correctly in the UV editor. UV shows up correctly in Edit mode.
- Switching the texture to one which is showing up correctly on another mesh has no effect. This mesh still shows up as black.

I've checked the shader in the materials panel and also in the shader editor. It looks right, and it looks the same as the other meshes that are working.

Texture does show if I switch the 3D view to "render" but that's slow and I have another problem which I think this problem is causing, so I have to solve it. (When I bake the texture from this model to another, it shows up black.)

I've run out of things to try. Any ideas?

Screenshot showing the model selected, some other models in the same scene showing correctly, the image that should be shown, and the materials panel.

[image: 3D view]

[image: Shader editor for the problematic mesh]

Comment: please show a screenshot

Comment: Hey :). So the mesh shows any texture as black, but only in Eevee (material preview)?

Comment: Screenshot. Shows model selected in 3d view along with two other meshes which are showing correctly. Shows texture in upper right and material in lower right.

Comment: Erm, screenshot coming as soon as I figure out how.

Comment: I *think* I'm using cycles, not eevee. But, noob here. Is material preview always eevee? Then that's what I'm using.

Comment: ![screenshot](https://photos.app.goo.gl/34jtSdZo41re1pvN6)

Comment: please show the Shader Editor so that we can see the node organization (and put the screenshot in your initial question)

Comment: Done, @moonboots

Comment: You specified your material output as *Cycles* - try changing it to **All**.

Comment: That did it. Based on the above comments, I think I even understand why. Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Fixing the material output to match what the 3D layer is using per above suggestion fixed the problem.

The image of the *Shader Editor* above shows that the *Material Output* node is set to *Cycles*. But Blender has several render engines, Cycles and Eevee in particular.

In the image of the 3D View above, the view is set to show Materials. (Circle highlighted in blue in the lower right corner). The materials view uses the EEVEE renderer.

So the key is the material output has to match the active renderer in the 3D view. *All* or *EEVEE * in the *Material Output* produce an EEVEE output the renderer can use. Cycles, which I had set for no good reason, does not.

Answer (score 4):

In hopes this can help not just you but also people finding this thread in future, here's some things to check to better understand the problem:

- disconnect the image texture from the shader and manually set the base color to see if it's a texture issue at all (in OP's case it isn't)
- change the background color (*World Properties* tab [image]) to see if the issue is black color of the model or transparency:

[image]

As for the solutions:

- in viewport shading settings try deselecting *Scene World* or selecting *Scene Lights*:

[image]

- in *Material Properties* tab make sure *Blending Mode* is *Opaque*:

[image]

- in *Shader Editor* make sure the *Material Output* is set to **All**:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem and worked it out by disabling *Screen Space Refraction*

Comment: Hi, thanks for the post. This site is not a regular forum, answers should be substantial, stand on their own, and thoroughly explain the solution and procedure. One liners and short tips rarely make for a good answer. If you can [edit] your post and provide some more details about the workflow and how it works, feel free to restore it, otherwise it may be converted to a comment. Perhaps add a few [images](https://blender.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/963) illustrating some steps and final result. See [How to write a good answer?](https://blender.stackexchange.com/help/how-to-answer)